# CrunchyData Postgres operator Pod always in pending state

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, persistent-volumes, crunchy-postgresql-operator, postgres-operator

I am trying to set up Postgres cluster using CrunchyData Postgres operator. I am facing issue where the pod `backrest-shared-repo` is always in `Pending` state.

```
NAME                      STATUS    VOLUME   CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
postgres-ha-1             Pending                                                     12m
postgres-ha-1-pgbr-repo   Pending                                                     12m
```

While debugging I found that the `PersistentVolumeClaim` is also in pending state. Events of `PVC` is below:

```
no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set
```

**PVC.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2022-07-08T10:28:48Z"
  finalizers:
  - kubernetes.io/pvc-protection
  labels:
    pg-cluster: postgres-ha-1
    vendor: crunchydata
  name: postgres-ha-1-pgbr-repo
  namespace: pgo
  resourceVersion: "1786569"
  uid: 6f80d516-320c-490e-ad6a-83400ea998a4
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 3G
  volumeMode: Filesystem
status:
  phase: Pending
```

Below is the storage configuration in `postgres-operator.yml`:

```
backrest_storage: "hostpathstorage"
backup_storage: "hostpathstorage"
primary_storage: "hostpathstorage"
replica_storage: "hostpathstorage"
pgadmin_storage: "hostpathstorage"
wal_storage: ""
storage1_name: "default"
storage1_access_mode: "ReadWriteOnce"
storage1_size: "1G"
storage1_type: "dynamic"
storage2_name: "hostpathstorage"
storage2_access_mode: "ReadWriteMany"
storage2_size: "3G"
storage2_type: "create"
storage3_name: "nfsstorage"
storage3_access_mode: "ReadWriteMany"
storage3_size: "1G"
storage3_type: "create"
storage3_supplemental_groups: "65534"
storage4_name: "nfsstoragered"
storage4_access_mode: "ReadWriteMany"
storage4_size: "1G"
storage4_match_labels: "crunchyzone=red"
storage4_type: "create"
storage4_supplemental_groups: "65534"
storage5_name: "storageos"
storage5_access_mode: "ReadWriteOnce"
storage5_size: "5Gi"
storage5_type: "dynamic"
storage5_class: "fast"
storage6_name: "primarysite"
storage6_access_mode: "ReadWriteOnce"
storage6_size: "4G"
storage6_type: "dynamic"
storage6_class: "primarysite"
storage7_name: "alternatesite"
storage7_access_mode: "ReadWriteOnce"
storage7_size: "4G"
storage7_type: "dynamic"
storage7_class: "alternatesite"
storage8_name: "gce"
storage8_access_mode: "ReadWriteOnce"
storage8_size: "300M"
storage8_type: "dynamic"
storage8_class: "standard"
storage9_name: "rook"
storage9_access_mode: "ReadWriteOnce"
storage9_size: "1Gi"
storage9_type: "dynamic"
storage9_class: "rook-ceph-block"
```

Can anyone help me in solving the issue?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a `PersistentVolume` in the cluster before you can use it with a `PersistentVolumeClaim`. The error simply means you do not have any PVs that can be matched with your PVC.

Here's the official [guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/) on how to create `PersistentVolumes`. Just ensure that the specifications you set on the `PersistentVolume` match the `PersistentVolumeClaim`, otherwise it will not be bound.

You can use an `hostPath` type PV which will simply create a directory on your worker node and use it to store data. This will prove the functional correctness. Later perhaps you can move towards a more central solution of having a centralized Volume store (details in the docs [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/)).

Comment: why it is required to create the `PersistentVolume` manually? It should be handled by the crunchy data operator.

Comment: More accurately, it should be handled by the operator _deployment_. When the operator is installed, the instructions should specify/provide a manifest for creating a PersistentVolume. But unfortunately, in your case, they probably have not, and you're seeing this problem.